# Debian server Systemd-journald use high CPU

Tags: ubuntu, debian, systemd-journald

systemd-journal seems to have hig CPU usage(60~70%)

```
# journalctl
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_OUT:IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=120 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=25585 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=43
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=120 TOS=0x00
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=120 TOS=0x00
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_OUT:IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=160 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=54980 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_OUT:IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=160 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=54980 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=160 TOS=0x08
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=160 TOS=0x08
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_OUT:IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=120 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=25586 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=43
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_OUT:IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=120 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=25586 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=43
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=120 TOS=0x00
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=120 TOS=0x00
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_OUT:IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=160 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=54981 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_OUT:IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=160 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=54981 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=160 TOS=0x08
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=160 TOS=0x08
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_OUT:IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=120 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=25587 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=43
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_OUT:IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=120 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=25587 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=43
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=120 TOS=0x00
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=120 TOS=0x00
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_OUT:IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=160 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=54982 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33
Jun 11 17:31:14 hotname.example kernel: BANDWIDTH_OUT:IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=160 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=54982 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33
```

And /var/log/debug ,syslog,bandwidth,kern.log file size increases very quickly.

What is the cause? What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906251/systemd-journald-high-cpu-usage) on Ask Ubuntu.  Maybe you can find an an answer there.